# REST endpoint: how to proper design an action on a resource?

Tags: rest, url, architecture, api-design, restful-architecture

I have the resource `/contracts` with the following structure:

```
{
    name: "Contract name",
    signedAt: 123213231,
    // etc.
}
```

While basic CRUD operations are well clear (**GET** `/contracts`, **GET** `/contracts/{id}`, **POST** `/contracts`, etc.) some doubts come when I have to do some concrete actions on the resource.

One of these actions is the following:

- **sign**: means the contract is signed, so the `signedAt` date will need to be updated with the moment (date-time) the contract was signed.

So far I've been thinking about these different approaches:

## PATCH-ing the resource

This approach will mean having the following endpoint method:

**PATCH** `/contracts/{id}`

and just posting the `signedAt` date `{ signedAt: 123213231 }` meaning that after this the contract will be signed.

What I don't like about this approach is that the signature date comes from the client, I was thinking that having this date initialized on the backend side whenever a contract is signed could be better and more consistent.

> Totally discarded, as the signedAt date should be set on the server
>   side exactly at the moment the sign is done.

## POST-ing a new resource

This approach will mean having the signature action as a resource:

**POST** `/contracts/{id}/sign`

with an empty body in this case as we don't need to pass anything else so, once it is posted, the backend side would be the responsible for having the signature date initialized.

## POST-ing the resource using 'action'

Similar to the previous approach, in this case I would use a query parameter called `action` on the contract resource:

**POST** `/contracts/{idContract}?action=sign`

also with an empty body where `?action=sign`. Like in the previous approach, once posted the backend side would be the responsible for having the signature date initialized.

#### Questions

- What would be the proper way to have this designed at a REST API level?
- Is any of the approaches above close to a good design or not?
- Would I need to modify any of the approaches?
- Is there any better alternative?

Comment: Why not patch using signed=true and then change the date into backend

Comment: @VeselinDavidov you mean `signed=true` as a query parameter? or in the body? If passed in the body it would be ignored as the contract resource itself does not have this property you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I have designed a few rest APIs myself but I am not a restful evangelist so my answer might not be the best. I would suggest some of the following:

- Create a custom converter for date values in your rest service that accepts date AND other specific fields. If you checkGoogle reporting APIs for example they allow you to use specific date range and also CURRENT_WEEK, CURRENT_MONTH etc. So you can add such specific value and use it. For example PATCH signedAt=CURRENT_DATE and the API handles that properly.
- Add a boolean signed field to the resource. Do a POST or PATCH with signed=true. This way you will be able to eventually query only signed resources easily ;) Also it might be the case that people care only about if it is signed than when it was signed

I wouldn't use ?action=sign or /contracts/{id}/sign because these are not RESTFUL and even if you do use GET and POST you would use them in a way to create a workaround in order to implement actions in your design which shouldn't have actions

Comment: If you **PATCH** `/contracts/{id}` you should send a subset of the requested resource properties of the specified contract you want to partially update. If you specify in a POST/PUT/PATCH body a property not defined in a resource, this property not be taken into account. If my contract resource does not have a `signed` property as part of its definition, that signed=true should be ignored. That's not even REST.

Comment: eg. say my resource 'foo' has the following structure: `{ id: 1, a: "1", b: "2" }`. If you **PATCH** `/foos/1` with the following body: `{ signed: true }` nothing should happen, as `signed` is not part of the resource foo's definition.

Comment: Yeah that's why I said you might want to add the signed so it is part of the resource. If you don't want to add it then use the other solution. Provide a custom values that are interpreted by the backend and calculated there. For example PATCH /resource/{id}    with payload signedAt=CURRENT_DATE and the backend will see CURRENT_DATE and sets the server timestamp

Comment: In the foo example if 'b' is your date you would be able to do PATCH /foo/1 with body { b: CURRENT_SERVER_TIME } and make the server change that to real date

Comment: Adding that `signed` flag for me does not add any value. I don't like having several properties that represent the same, there's a lot more checks to do to keep this "duplicated" information consistent, among other things. Because in this case, you already know if a contract is signed by checking if it has a signature date already. Once signed, it cannot be unsigned anymore or have the signature date updated. For that reason, I think it is more interesting to set that date on the backend side.

Comment: I found the following GitHub API for starring/unstarring a Gist: https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#star-a-gist in that case, the approach is pretty similar to what I am looking for. You don't want to send the number of stars of a gist and update it, in this case (same as mine) you just want to know some kind of action happened and do some stuff safely on the backend side.

Comment: Yeah then ignore that adding a signed field and check the first part of my answer. Make your resource accept other values than just dates - like CURRENT_TIME. And that date will be calculated in the backend

Comment: From a security point of view, your first point does not convince me as the client is the one that is actually passing you a value that should be set on the server side instead at the very moment that action is being done.

Comment: Check also: https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful => the section called: *What about actions that don't fit into the world of CRUD operations?*.
But honestly, your effort trying to help here is very appreciated! :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> just posting the signedAt date { signedAt: 123213231 } meaning that after this the contract will be signed.

On [HTTP Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2)

> The set of changes is represented in a format called a "patch document" identified by a media type.

Rather than rolling your own bespoke media type, you might want to consider whether one of the standard formats is suitable.

For example: [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902).

```
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[ { "op": "replace", "path": "signedAt", "value": 123213231 }
```

[JSON Merge Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396) is another reasonable option

```
Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json

{ signedAt: 123213231 }
```

From what I can see, the primary difference is that JSON Patch provides a [test operation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4.6) which gives you finer grain control than simply relying upon [validators](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-2)

But you are absolutely right - PATCH gives the client code authority to specify the time value.  If that's not appropriate for your use case, then PATCH is the wrong tool in the box.

```
POST /contracts/{id}/sign
POST /contracts/{idContract}?action=sign
```

As far as REST/HTTP are concerned, these two choices are equivalent -- you are updating the state of one resource by sending an unsafe request to a *different* resource.  There are some mild differences in how these spellings act when [resolving references](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5), but as request-targets, it doesn't make a difference to the client.

An option that you seem to have overlooked:

```
POST /contracts/{id}

action=sign
```

This has the advantage that, when successful, you get [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) for free.

In a hypermedia API, the flow might go something like this: the client would `GET` the resource; because the resource hasn't been signed yet, the representation could include a form, with a "sign" button on it.  The action on the form would be `/contracts/{id}`.  The consumer "signs" the contract by submitting the form -- the agent gathers up the information described by the form, encodes it into the request body, and then posts the request to the server.  The server responds success, and the client's cache knows to *invalidate* the previously fetched copy of the resource.